# Adding an element to the ordered link list

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have the following *addEngine function that adds elements to my linked list, which I want to sort in ascending order by year. I must not change the function arguments.

It doesn't work the way I imagine. Why is

```
a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2015) );
```

not included when listing in main?

```
  typedef struct TEngine 
{
    struct TEngine *m_Next;
    int m_Year;
    char m_Type [ TYPE_MAX ];
} TENGINE;

  typedef struct TArchive
{
    struct TArchive *m_Next;
    TENGINE *m_Engines;
} TARCHIVE;

TARCHIVE *addEngine ( TARCHIVE *list, TENGINE *engine) 
{
    TARCHIVE *res = (TARCHIVE*) malloc(sizeof(*res));

    if ( list == NULL )
    {
        res -> m_Next = NULL;
        return res;
    }

    int currentYear = list -> m_Engnes -> m_Year;
    if ( currentYear > engine -> m_Year )
    {
        TARCHIVE *prev = list;
        TARCHIVE *current = list -> m_Next; 

        while ( current != NULL )
        {
            if ( currentYear >= engine -> m_Year )
            {
                 res -> m_Next = prev -> m_Next;
                 prev -> m_Next = res;
                 return list;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current -> m_Next;
        } 
        prev -> m_Next = res; 
        res -> m_Next = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}

      int main ( void )
     {
          TARCHIVE *a, *b;
          b = a = NULL;
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2015) );
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 3001 ) );
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TSI 1.2", 1999 ) );
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 2.0", 2108 ) );
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2005) );
          b = a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 1010 ) );
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2025) );
          a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 2038 ) );

          while ( b )
        {
            printf ("%s", b -> m_Engines -> m_Type);
            b = b -> m_Next;``
        }
```

Comment: User Aaron7 asked the exact question before. Seems you are using more than one user name. Anyway, this code is still incomplete to be able to help you. I suggest you take a debugger and step through it.

Comment: In order to have a Minimum Reproducible Example you have to provide at least `TARCHIVE` and `TENGINE` structure and a simple main in which you call your add function. Ps: and explaining *2015 issue*.

Comment: You are calling `AddEnding` with three parameters, but it only takes two?! Please provide a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally copied it.

Comment: I added structures. The create function should probably not affect this problem.

Comment: Style issue: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be used with spaces around them.  Writing `res -> m_Next` is not idiomatic C; use `res->m_Next`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just 2015. It is for all things you add. Because you do add list structures, *but never put the engine structure in the list structure*!

It seems that when the first item didn't work, you didn't check if any next item worked.

You are also printing `b` but forgot to do `b = a;` before you started printing.

So to start, you should do:

```
if ( list == NULL )
{
    res -> m_Next = NULL;
    res -> m_Engines = engine;  // add this line
    return res;
}
```

and then also do that where you insert/add an item to the list.

And could you please explain why both `TARCHIVE` and `TENGINE` have an `m_Next`? Which one is your list?

I also note that when `if ( currentYear > engine -> m_Year )` fails, you don't do anything. So if `list -> m_Engnes -> m_Year` (the first list element) is greater or equal, you ignore the engine. You should put it in front.

And note the typo in `m_Engnes`; that should be `m_Engines`. Didn't your compiler warn you? Please turn warnings of your compiler on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. What else should I modify? Because the problem persists, but I suppose I missed something.

```
TARCHIVE *AddEngine  ( TARCHIVE *list, TENGINE *engine )
{

  TARCHIVE * res = ( TARCHIVE * ) malloc ( sizeof ( *res ) );


    if ( list == NULL )
   {
      res -> m_Next = NULL;
      res -> m_Engines = engine;
      return res;
   }

     int currentYear = list->m_Engines->m_Year;


    // The inserted element is smaller than the first
    if ( currentYear > engine->m_Year )
  {      
      res -> m_Next = list;
      res -> m_Engines = engine;
      return res;
  }

    TARCHIVE *prev = list;
    TARCHIVE *current = list -> m_Next;

    while ( current != NULL )
  {
        currentYear = current->m_Engines->m_Year;

        if ( currentYear >= engine->m_Year )  
     {
            res -> m_Next = prev -> m_Next;
            res -> m_Engines = engine;
            prev -> m_Next = res;

            return list;
     }

        prev = current;
        current = current -> m_Next;
  }

    prev -> m_Next = res;
    res -> m_Engines = engine;
    res -> m_Next = NULL;
    return res;
}

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to ask a question, please use the comments or edit your question.

Comment: 'm sorry, I just wanted to show the modified code because I probably missed something from the previous board and I can't find it.